# Realm Swift: "Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction.", despite RLMArray being in a transaction?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

everyone.

I've recently been using MongoDB Realm for Swift UI and it has been very good so far, but now I'm facing a problem that I have spent a lot of time trying to fix but to no avail.

To begin, I'm creating a simple To Do app to get used to the database, and I have created two entities, the `Task`, and the `TaskGroup`.

Naturally, there is a relationship between these two entities and that is a `TaskGroup` object contains many `Task` objects using `List<Task>`, and I would backlink the object using `LinkingObjects<TaskGroup>`.

Now, the issue is when I add a task group, there is no issues and the new task group is visible on the screen, but all hell breaks loose when I begin to add a task to the task group's `tasks` property, which is `List<Task>`, as for some reason, Realm throws an error saying that the task I'm appending is outside the realm transaction, even though it is, and I'm following the Realm tutorial.

I have a created a class to manage realms that I create, which includes a custom configuration (the rest of the code is singleton method and declaration):

```
class RealmManager
{  
    /* ... */

    public static func Initialize() -> Void
    {
        /* Path to the realm. */
        let path: String = ".../Markdown.realm"

        /* The schema version must be updated every time we modify the schema. */
        var config = Realm.Configuration /* -> */ (
            schemaVersion: 6
        )
        
        config.fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Here are the class for the `Task` and `TaskGroup` entities:

```
final class Task: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable
{
    // Attributes
    
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true)
    public var id: ObjectId
    
    @Persisted
    var title: String
    
    @Persisted
    var note: String
    
    @Persisted
    var date: Date
    
    @Persisted
    var complete: Bool
    
    @Persisted
    var priority: Int
    
    @Persisted(originProperty: "tasks")
    public var parent_group: LinkingObjects<TaskItemGroup>
    
    /* ... */
}
```

```
final class TaskGroup: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable
{
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true)
    public var id: ObjectId
    
    @Persisted
    public var title: String
    
    @Persisted
    public var color: String
    
    @Persisted
    public var icon: String
    
    @Persisted
    public var tasks: RealmSwift.List<TaskItem>
    
    /* ... */
}
```

And finally, here is the class where the issue is (I believe):

```
struct TaskAddSheet: View
{ 
    /* ... */

    @ObservedRealmObject
    private var m_parent_task_group: TaskItemGroup
    
    init(_ obj: TaskGroup)
    {
        m_parent_task_group = obj
    }
    
    private func AddTask() -> Void
    {
        do
        {
            let realm: Realm = try Realm()
            
            let entry: TaskItem = TaskItem()
            
            try realm.write {
                entry.title = m_title
                entry.note = m_note
                entry.date = m_date
                entry.priority = m_priority
                
                m_parent_task_group.tasks.append(entry)

                realm.add(entry)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("[Insert Error] - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        /* Dismiss the current view. */
        m_dismiss_action()
    }

    /* The rest is the view body. */
}
```

```
struct TaskGroupAddSheet: View
{
    private func AddTaskGroup() -> Void
    {
        do
        {
            let realm: Realm = try Realm()

            let entry: TaskItemGroup = TaskItemGroup()

            try realm.write {
                entry.title = m_title
                entry.color = m_color
                entry.icon = m_icon
                entry.tasks = RealmSwift.List<TaskItem>()
                
                realm.add(entry)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("[Error] - \(error)")
        }
        
        /* Dismiss the current view. */
        m_dismiss_action()
    }
    
    /* The rest is the view body. */
}
```

Please let me know if you need more code samples so that I can add them if you need more information.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have trimmed the code and took out any empty initializers, line breaks, etc., to make reading the code clearer.

EDIT 2: I have renamed my entities `Task` to `TaskItem`, and `TaskGroup` to `TaskItemGroup`.

SOLVED: I needed to write `$m_parent_task_group.append(entry)` instead, which solved the problem. Now the program adds the tasks to the group without any problems.

Comment: I highly suggest renaming `Task` and `TaskGroup`, considering those are already types in Swift and you'll end up with collisions.

Comment: @jnpdx They are? I don't have anything in Swift matching that in my XCode.

Comment: That's a whole lotta code for us to parse through and there's a tremendous amount of white space. Can you  par down that code for us into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Taking out all of those spaces will really help shorten the question. Also, if you've commented stuff out and the problem persists, leave it out of the question as well.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing `self.init()` in your realm objects `init` - and if you don't actually need those, remove them. Otherwise `convenience init` is the way to go if you want some default initializers.

Comment: @Jay https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup

Comment: @jnpdx Well, a gigantic DUH on me. Of course `Task` is a thing! I use it with `try await` async functions in macOS Apps. Thanks for the reminder. Yeah probably best to avoid that name - even though the use and context are different. I would still like the see reduced code in the question with a clearer example.

Comment: @jnpdx OK I will rename them and see what happens.

Comment: @Jay Sorry about that, It's just I didn't know what leave out, I'll make changes.

Comment: @jnpdx I've renamed them to ```TaskItem``` and ```TaskItemGroup``` but sadly the issue still persists, saying that RLM array was modified outside a transaction.

Comment: @Jay As for the ```init```, I was only following the official Realm documentation and tutorial, and they didn't use any ```init``` outside some convenience ones here and there. Though I'm not certain if play a role in the problem. :(

Comment: I didn’t mean to imply that renaming would solve your issue — just that it was likely to be another pain point.

Comment: Some things: you don't need to do both this `m_parent_task_group.tasks.append(entry)` and then this `realm.add(entry)`. Realm is pretty smart and if and object is created and appended to another object within a write, it will automatically become a managed object and written to disk. Also, this line `entry.tasks = RealmSwift.List<TaskItem>()` doesn't actually do anything as that property is instantiated when the object is. Lastly, your view property is being instantied with the wrong class type `m_parent_task_group = obj` where `obj` should be a `TaskItemGroup` not a `TaskGroup`

Comment: Okay! I didn't know that ```append()``` also writes the object to the database. And also that last error is a typo, I forgot to change the name. I also managed to solve the issue as a whole by adding a $ at the beginning of ```m_parent_task_group.append(entry)```. I will update the question. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You may want to try `m_parent_task_group.thaw()`. I bet that property is frozen.